# How to read list of string

Tags: vb.net

I have this:

Public stringList As New List(Of String)

I need to read the whole list using For each statement, what is the best way to do so using VB.net syntax?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it would be worth you reading [the MSDN documentation for the For Each ... Next statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx).

For example:

```
For Each x As String In stringList
    Console.WriteLine(x)
Next
```

If that's not what you're after, please give more details in your question.